# MySql - Find a row, get a value then get random record using the obtained below

Tags: mysql

I have searched the forum but could not find the answer. Perhaps it is an obvious answer but I am taking my first baby steps in mysql.

This works well:

```
SELECT * FROM `uniquein_jo163`.`jos_facileforms_subrecords` 
WHERE name = 'overallexperience' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

But I wish to have the above code work, the row that comes up, in that there is a column called record - get its value then run the above query using the value of the record obtained.

Can this be done?
Thank you

Ok. I explain more. All on the same table. The table I have is complicated (atleast it seems to me). This table gets its data from many web forms (using breezingforms on joomla)

First step: 
Column title is - name
so search the table where the value of name is equal to 'overallexperience'

image 1 shows the result of this query

2nd step:
once this row is found, from the same row get the value of another column called record. In this case it is 50

3rd step:
perform the select* query again with the search string where record = the value obtained in the 2nd step.

At the end of 3rd step I shall many rows of record = the value obtained.

image 2 shows this result

Now I need to display the values of firstname, lastname, country, overallexperience etc. on the web page.
Can this be done?![image1][1]![image2][2]

Well i am not allowed to post images.
so, i try with the link [image1][1] not working

please visit http://uniqueindiatour.com/image1.png
and visit
http://uniqueindiatour.com/image2.png

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve ?

Comment: A little more context would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `uniquein_jo163`.`jos_facileforms_subrecords`
WHERE
    `name` = (
        SELECT
            `record`
        FROM
            `uniquein_jo163`.`jos_facileforms_subrecords`
        WHERE
            `name` = 'overallexperience'
        ORDER BY
            RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it returning 0 rows? Or is it returning (an) unexpected row(s)?

Comment: I get this message: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.5149 sec )

Comment: If you're getting an empty result set then it means no record matches the criteria given in the query.